# Influencing Permissions-Handling on Fedora with Gimp?

Tags: permissions, apache-http-server, fedora, images, gimp

I'm including some pictures into a website by scanning a bunch of folders on my local machine for images via PHP and automatically generating the necessary HTML-code (`<img...>`). But the Browser doesn't show the pictures, instead - following the link to the image - "Forbidden: You don't have permission to access...".

Permissions are set to 755 (folders) and 644 (files). When I open the images in Gimp and save them as new files the browser will show them, even though I didn't change anything; just opening and saving. The thing is, I have hundreds of pictures and I don't want to proceed with opening every picture individually. **The new file and the original file do have the same permissions.** Here is proof:
[The file with the underscore in the end works (Baummarder Mai 14_.JPG). The rest does not.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIaUI.png)

To be clear: I have working and non-working pictures in the same folder. The ones that I saved as new files with Gimp are shown while the original ones (in the same folder) show the "acces denied" default image.

Error_log says:

```
(13)Permission denied: [client 127.0.0.1:38192] AH00035: access to /auwaldstation/quiz/Wildkamera/Bilder/Wildschwein/SchweinCdy00008.JPG denied (filesystem path '/var/www/html/auwaldstation/quiz/Wildkamera/Bilder/Wildschwein/SchweinCdy00008.JPG') because search permissions are missing on a component of the path, referer: http://localhost/auwaldstation/quiz/wildkamera_bilder.php
```

Even though the *complete* filepath ist set to 755.

(Don't mind that it is a different file in a different subfolder - permissions and way of including it in the page IS the same)

I'm very curious about what might be the problem. Could it be due to meta-data? I checked those but couldn't find anything obvious. Is it possible that those files are somehow damaged or have wrong metadata/header or whatever that can evoke such a behavior? Is it a weird bug/feature of permissions handling i.e. files that i did not create i do not own?

Is there some way to solve that problem? Is it possible to show those pictures anyway using some PHP-magic?

**UPDATE**:
I just found out that the following PHP-code does not recognize the original pictures as images at all. The newly created ones it does recognize as images though.

```
function is_image($path)
{
    $a = getimagesize($path);
    $image_type = $a[2];

    if(in_array($image_type , array(IMAGETYPE_GIF , IMAGETYPE_JPEG ,IMAGETYPE_PNG , IMAGETYPE_BMP)))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Btw: the pictures are taken by a trail cam. There is no copyright conflict involved.

Using: Fedora 23, Apache 2.4.23, PHP, HTML/CSS

Comment: The error message states quite clearly that a directory in the path is missing the "execute" flag... In any case Errno=13 doesn't come from data in the file because it means the file couldn't be read at all.

Comment: as i wrote in my post i have pictures that are working in exactly the same folder than pictures that are not working. so it is definitely not due to a missing "execute" flag.

Comment: But why couldn't the file be read at all??? the only difference between the files that can be read and the ones that can not is that I created the ones that can be read with Gimp. The files are in the same folder, permissions are the same. There's no htaccess-file, no nothing.

Comment: You have a dot at the end of your permissions flags...  that means there are some SELinux permissions set as well...

Comment: thx, never heard of selinux context before

Comment: Neither did I :) Just wondered what the bl**dy dot was...

Comment: SELinux: UAC for Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution had to do with SELINUX context. Changed the context via chcon. Now it works.
http://www.linux-commands-examples.com/chcon

Comment: Heh, been there seen that. Wasted quite some time on debugging build and access errors when setting up www.gimp.org because all of it failed without identifying SELinux  as the root cause.